# Directory level access in git

Tags: git

I have one repository in git which has many sub-projects.Like this

repo

```
parent project
   |
   |----project 1
   |----project 2
   |----project 3
   |----project 4
```

Now, I would like to give access such that user1 can access only project1, user2 can access only project2 and so on.

I have gone through these links but didn't suffice my requirements.

- [Per-directory permissions on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139934/per-directory-permissions-on-git)
- https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Thanks

Imran

Comment: You shouldn't put more than one project into one repository. It would be a better idea to put each project in its own repository.

Comment: Git is not design for granular ACL, per-directories permissions is worth the effort. It won't be much difference hosting one git repos or multiple git repos.

Answer (score 1):

I think git won't have this feature. You can use `Gerrit` (Web based code review and project management for Git based projects).