# Git, sharing subfolders

Tags: git

We have a git repository with N folders.

```
Repo
|-Folder1
|-Folder2
|- ...
|-FolderN
```

With different collaborators we would like to share a different subset of folders. Each collaborator should have access only to his allowed subset of folders. What is the "good" way to achieve this using git?

Comment: probably by making folder1, folder2, foldern seperate repos, I doubt there is a way otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Per-directory permissions on git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139934/per-directory-permissions-on-git)

Comment: @AD7six if we create separate repos, would it still be possible to pull them together, push them together, ..., without the need for writing customized scripts to do such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using groups/organizations on [Gitlab](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/groups.html)/Github. I'm more familiar with Gitlab, but it will let you add people as "roles" (developer, observer) to certain subprojects in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly disallowing developers write access to each other's folders, then I suggest you should be using a dependency package manager like composer or npm. Each developer would have their own repository. Then you have a super project that includes all developer's work as a project dependency.