# Can we restrict access to submodules files in the Git repository

Tags: git, version-control, permissions

I am new to Git, I want to submodule my repository in to the developer repository from where I deploy the code,  I want restrict access those files from developers to view, Can I secure file of Submodules of Git

Comment: Are you referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139934/per-directory-permissions-on-git

Comment: Yes similar to this, What I mean is Project1 & Project2 are two repositories with different permissions, Project1 contains secure files. We use master branch of Project2 to deploy to  Prod. I want to used the files in the Project1 too but developer who have access to the Project2 master branch don't want to see my files if I submodule my repository(Project1) into Project2 . We use Visual studio online to deploy the code. How can we do this?